# Setting up a convention for automatic factories

Tags: c#, ninject, factory, convention-over-configur

By defining a `IDataRepositoryFactory` non-generic interface with a generic `Create` method:

```
public interface IDataRepositoryFactory
{
    T Create<T>(DataContext context) where T : IDataRepository; // new non-generic interface
}
```

I'm able to avoid having to write factory implementations:

```
        _kernel.Bind(t => t.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(DataRepository<>))
                           .SelectAllInterfaces()
                           .EndingWith("RepositoryFactory")
                           .BindToFactory());

        _kernel.Bind(t => t.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(DataRepository<>))
                           .SelectAllClasses()
                           .WhichAreNotGeneric()
                           .EndingWith("Repository")
                           .BindAllInterfaces());
```

However this solution has pros and cons:

Pros:

- No need to manually implement abstract factories anymore.

Cons:

- Having this `IDataRepositoryFactory` interface as a dependency, feels a lot like using a *service locator*:

  - The all-powerful generic factory can create *any* repository type, even those in namespaces of completely unrelated modules.
  - Actual dependencies are now hidden behind an abstract factory; the consumer's constructor no longer statically documents the required repositories/factories.

Is there not a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic Factory interfaces aren't currently supported. So, that's already the best you can do.