# Error activating IInterceptor... only through COM?

Tags: c#, vb6, ninject, com-interop

**TL;DR: `Kernel.Get<T>` works when called from a .net/WPF app, but blows up with an inner `ActivationException` (inside a `TargetInvocationException`) when called from a VB6 app. WTH?**

This is a bit of a follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729630/setting-up-a-convention-for-automatic-factories) where I configured an abstract factory with Ninject conventions, in such a way that I never need to actually implement one, the Ninject factory extension takes care of generating one on-the-fly.

This worked beautifully... until I needed to run my library from VB6 code.

```
_kernel.Bind(t => t.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(ViewModelBase))
       .SelectAllInterfaces()
       .EndingWith("ViewFactory")
       .BindToFactory());
```

As soon as I call anything on the app from VB6 code, if I wrap the resolving of dependencies inside a try/catch block, I'm trapping a `TargetInvocationException` with an inner `ActivationException`:

> Error activating IInterceptor using conditional implicit self-binding
>   of IInterceptor Provider returned null. Activation path:
>
> 3) Injection of dependency IInterceptor into parameter  of constructor of type IViewFactoryProxy
>
> 2) Injection of dependency IViewFactory into parameter viewFactory of constructor of type MsgBox
>
> 1) Request for IMsgBox
>
> Suggestions:
>
> 1) Ensure that the provider handles creation requests properly.

I have no reference to the Ninject.Interception extension (at this point).

Oddly if instead of launching VB6 I launch a sandbox WPF test app when I debug, I don't get any `ActivationException` and everything works like a charm.

The VB6 code dies with `automation error -2146232828 (80131604)` which yields nothing on Google, but I'm guessing it has to do with the `TargetInvocationException` being thrown.

As far as .net code is concerned *it just works*: if I compose the app from a WPF client I can break in the `MsgBox` class constructor and see that the `IViewFactory` parameter is happy with a `Castle.Proxy.IViewFactoryProxy`; if I compose the app from a VB6 ActiveX DLL (I also created a VB6 EXE to test and same as the DLL), it blows up.

### UPDATE

I removed the generic abstract factories, and I no longer get this error. And because I don't want to be writing factories, I went for a bit of tighter coupling that I can live with. Now I'd like to know *why* this was happening!

Comment: I suspect I might be encountering the same problem by attempting to use a Module configured with Ninject Factory extensions inside the WPF designer. I'm not using conventions though, just a manually configured .ToFactory(). Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this exception today in a completely different context to you. I was trying to use a kernel configured with a custom module inside a design time view model in the VS WPF Designer. The module had a number of interfaces configured using the `ToFactory()` extension method.

The problem was that for some reason the `Ninject.Extensions.Factory.FuncModule` was not loaded automatically when I was initialising my kernel, possibly due to some trickery in the way the VS designer handles creating design time classes (maybe it didn't load the appropriate assembly or something, who knows).

I had a unit test that was creating one of these design time view models, and it worked perfectly, so it was definitely something related to the designer.

I fixed the issue by creating a special kernel for my design time view models.

```
public class DT_Kernel : StandardKernel
{
    public DT_Kernel()
        : base(new MyModule())
    {
        if (!HasModule(typeof(FuncModule).FullName)) 
        {
            Load(new[] { new FuncModule() });
        }
    }
}
```

The important part of this code is the bit that loads the FuncModule if it isn't already loaded.

You might be able to leverage that code to fix your issue.

Comment: maybe it's related to how the "application" (vb6, VS designer) is loading the assemblies. By default ninject will load the Modules of all "ninject.extensions.*.dll" in the path where the entry(?) assembly is located. Maybe with vb6 and VS designer the entry assembly location is not available/not correct.

Comment: If I get a chance I'll see if I can add some logging into the code that initializes the design time view models, writing out to a known log file. I can check the entry/executing assembly and where its located and see whether or not the Ninject libraries are there.

Comment: Wow, I just hit this exact same issue, working on a COM add-in for the VBE. Loading up my `StandardKernel` with a new `FuncModule` instance solved it: `private readonly IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new FuncModule());` - no need to create a custom kernel type, just to load a `Ninject.Extensions.Factory.FuncModule` into the kernel (which is basically what you did here). Funny to google up a problem, and find your solution on a question you asked... 2 years ago!

Comment: [Relevant Ninject wiki page](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Manually-Loading-the-Factory-Extension-into-the-Ninject-Kernel)