# Lifespan of DbContext in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

This has got to be a solved problem, I just can't seem to find an answer...

I have a WPF front-end in a class library that uses Ninject IoC container; each *View* uses a *ViewModel* that gets a *Model* constructor-injected, and the *Model* receives a class derived from `DbContext`, also in its constructor.

As I type these words it occurs to me that I could solve this problem by injecting a factory that creates a class derived from `DbContext`, but I'll just finish putting the problem *in context* here.

This setup makes each window own a *unit of work* - which is exactly what I want. The problem is that on one of these windows I want a *discard changes* command that reloads all entities from the context.

I read the only reliable way to do this is to `Dispose` the context and reinstantiate it.

- **Q1: How is this supposed to play well with Dependency Injection?**

I might have something like this:

```
public class SomeModel : ISomeModel
{
    private readonly SomeContext _context;
    public SomeModel(SomeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    /* some methods acting upon entities in _context */
}
```

What I'm thinking of is something like this:

```
public class SomeModel : ISomeModel
{
    private readonly IContextFactory<SomeContext> _factory;
    private SomeContext _context;
    public SomeModel(IContextFactory<SomeContext> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _context = _factory.Create();
    }

    public void DiscardChanges()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = _factory.Create();
    }

    /* some methods acting upon entities in _context */
}
```

- **Q2: Are there any known issues/pitfalls to this approach?**

Right now I'm binding `DbContext` like this, using Ninject's Conventions extension:

```
_kernel.Bind(t => t.From(_dataLayerAssembly)
                   .SelectAllClasses()
                   .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Context"))
                   .BindDefaultInterface()
                   .Configure(config => config.InCallScope()));
```

If I go with the above approach, I don't need this configuration anymore (besides I'm not 100% sure the context gets disposed when I think it does) and I gain full control over the context's timeline and disposal... but I feel like I'm breaking something in the pattern - not that I care much about breaking a pattern (not a "purist"), though I'm curious to see how a MVVM+DI "purist" would approach this.

Also I know Ninject has a *Factory* extension which could probably eliminate the need for factory classes, but [last time I used it, it broke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395022/error-activating-iinterceptor-only-through-com) - the class library must be usable by a VB6 ActiveX DLL, and the factory extension doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: I have posted the factory solution [here on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32156/enabling-discard-pending-changes-on-dbcontext), as I'd like to get some feedback on my code.

Comment: retailcoder: Why is there a requirement for a TContext to inherit DbContext? All you need is the IDisposable interface. I would go for: where TContext : IDisposable.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Hi, did you solve your problems with Unit of work in WPF?? I'm really curious how do you handle it. Do you have any code public? Btw. Why do you inject your UoW into Model and not into ViewModel?

Comment: @Marshall blast from the past! I ended up using a factory proxy type generated with Ninject's factory extension - turned out all that was missing for it to work was a NinjectModule I thought was "free", but had to be included explicitly (`FuncModule` it was). That code was private though, for a previous employer.. as for model vs viewmodel, ..good question, no idea lol I'd probably do things differently if I had to redo this today.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't use Ninject and I implemented my factory explicitly. Here is my code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/128430/105508
Can you look at this in a free time?